# How do I compile a subdirectory file in CLion?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, clion

I have a project named `CPrimerPlus6thEdition`. I'm trying to compile a standalone program called `FirstLastNames.c` which has its own `int main()` function. This is my folder structure.

```
/CPrimerPlus6thEdition  
|-- /ProgrammingExercises  
    |-- /2IntroducingC
        |--FirstLastNames.c
CMakeLists.txt
main.cpp
```

This is my `CMakeLists.txt` file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(CPrimerPlus6thEdition)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(CPrimerPlus6thEdition ${SOURCE_FILES})
add_executable(CPrimerPlus6thEdition/ProgrammingExercises/2IntroducingC ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_executable(target_name file1 file2 file3)
```

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_executable.html

The first argument is not a directory/path, it's the name of the target (and the name of the compiled executable file).

Try this as a replacement for the last 2 lines of your `CMakeLists.txt` file (I am assuming `/CPrimerPlus6thEdition` is the root of your CLion project):

```
add_executable(CPrimerPlus6thEdition ${SOURCE_FILES})
add_executable(FirstLastNames ProgrammingExercises/2IntroducingC/FirstLastNames.c)
```

And if you had another executable to compile, and say it was in /CPrimerPlus6thEdition/ProgrammingExercises/3Potato and had files Potato.c and Soil.c that needed to be compiled and linked:

```
add_executable(Potato ProgrammingExercises/3Potato/Potato.c ProgrammingExercises/3Potato/Soil.c)
```

Note that `FirstLastNames` and `Potato` are target names and are the name of the compiled executable file after building.